# In Python, how do I check that a file is a text file?

Tags: python, django

The file is uploaded through a Django form. The contents of the file need to be saved into a models.TextField(), for editors to review it before publication.

I am already checking UploadedFile.content_type. I have considered using a regular input field, but as the text is going to be quite long, it would be unwieldy for users to cut and paste.

Comment: Can you just check for the `.txt` extension?

Comment: Could you define text file a bit better?  Is it suppose to contain html or javascript? or are you concerned about binary files or word documents?

Comment: I am already doing that with UploadedFile.content_type, but that could easily be faked by spammers.

Comment: I am looking mainly to protect against binary files.

Comment: @Ludovico Fischer: "protect against binary files"  What will they do?  Something magical?  How will they do this?  Files are just files.  What "bad" thing can happen?

Comment: @S.Lott Well,editors will have to sift through a lot of garbage if the form gets targeted by spammers.

Comment: @Ludovico Fischer: So?    A file of all printable, clean ASCII can still be meaningless random "garbage".  How can you distinguish "garbage" from non-garbage uploads?  What's the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend on this one - see [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/173220-test-if-a-file-or-string-is-text-or-binary/)

Comment: Well, this seems the best answer; although the method is maybe a bit overkill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not all sequences of bytes are valid for ex. UTF-8, maybe you should check this?